# wp_get_attachment_url Repeating image

Tags: php, wordpress

Why this code just loop the same image? I want to display different images in the `<li>` html tag but it is just repeating the image.

```
$querystr = "
                SELECT wposts.ID, wposts.post_title
                FROM $wpdb->posts wposts
                WHERE wposts.post_type = 'attachment'
                AND wposts.post_mime_type = 'image/jpeg'
                ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
            ";

            $id = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, ARRAY_A);
            ) );

if(is_array($id) || is_object($id)){
                        //  var_dump($id);
                        //  echo "Total Photos: " . count($id);
                            foreach($id as $data){

                                $photo= wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $data->ID));
                                $title = wp_get_attachment_image($data->post_title);


                            echo '<li><img src="'.$photo.'" alt="'.$title.'"/></li>';
                                //var_dump($photo);
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: same image means only one image is repeating ?

Comment: yes @sarath can you help me with this

Comment: try to `print_r(  $id )` and see what data is coming.

Comment: `Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 225 [post_title] => Old Nuthatch Camera ) [1] => Array ( [ID] => 77 [post_title] => Feel free to use this image just link to www.rentvine.com ) [2] => Array ( [ID] => 681 [post_title] => IMG_0080 ) [3] => Array ( [ID] => 768 [post_title] => 4 img ) [4] => Array ( [ID] => 750 [post_title] => Casa 2 ) [5] => Array ( [ID] => 751 [post_title] => Casa 3 ) [6] => Array ( [ID] => 749 [post_title] => Casa 1 ) [7] => Array ( [ID] => 224 [post_title] => big camera ) [8] => Array ( [ID] => 745 [post_title] => IMG_0286 ) [9] => Array ( [ID] => 278 [post_title] => pat1 ) )`

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain thats the output sir please help.

Comment: its an array do it like `get_post_thumbnail_id( $data['ID'])`

Comment: currently listing the last image or first image ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You have syntax error right after `$id` which is brackets `) );`  remove it
2. Using `ARRAY_A` return Array result set ,where as you are using object which is wrong.
3. Use `wp_get_attachment_url` when you have attachment ID it will return image URL . **but** if you use `wp_get_attachment_url` and `get_post_thumbnail_id` together it will return only the image which attach with the post using `Featured Image` in **pages** or **post** section .
4. when Data is in **Array** form to retrieve data

**USE :** `$array['column_name']` 
OR

if it in **Object** USE : `$object->column_name`

So Correct code is.

```
    $querystr = "
                SELECT wposts.ID, wposts.post_title
                FROM $wpdb->posts wposts
                ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
            ";

$img_array = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, ARRAY_A);
// For Array 
if (is_array($img_array)) {

    foreach ($img_array as $data) {

        $photo = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($data['ID']));
        $title = ($data['post_title']);


        echo '<li><img src="' . $photo . '" alt="' . $title . '"/>' . $title . '</li>';

    }
}


// For Object 
$img_object = $wpdb->get_results($querystr);

if (is_object($img_object)) {

    foreach ($img_array as $data) {

        $photo = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($data->ID));
        $title = ($data->post_title);


        echo '<li><img src="' . $photo . '" alt="' . $title . '"/>' . $title . '</li>';

    }
}
```

Comment: yeah this one work, but just want to get the post image not all the image in media...thanks

Comment: you have to use `get_post_thumbnail_id` along with `wp_get_attachment_url` and change your query to get all posts `$querystr="SELECT wposts.ID, wposts.post_title  FROM $wpdb->posts wposts  ";`

Comment: don't know how to combine `get_post_thumbnail_id` can you add it to your answer please....thanks bro..

Comment: it is the same as you post in your question. `wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $data->ID));` if object   use : `$data->ID`
 OR Use For Array : `$data['ID']`

Comment: `wp_get_attachment_url(($data->ID));` this one is not working bro

Comment: are you using object or array ?

Answer (score 0):

For  selecting image from post you should select published posts.
change the query to

```
$querystr = "
                SELECT wposts.ID, wposts.post_title
                FROM $wpdb->posts wposts
                WHERE wposts.post_type = 'attachment'
                AND wposts.post_mime_type = 'image/jpeg'
                AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
                ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
            ";
```

Comment: do you have any published posts with attachment?

Comment: trying to output the images in portfolio

Comment: check table how the portfolio posts is saved. eg :  post_type ='portfolio'

Comment: `$project_types = get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'project-types', '<li><span class="split__title">'.__('Project Type', 'puremellow').'</span> ', ' / '); ` is this?